# Can not upload file to perl script using ajax/javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, perl

I have a form that takes a sinlge file image for upload to a perl script which uses binmode to read and save. The perl script does not seem to be getting the file stream (filesize ends up 0 bytes in size). I'm not sure if I'm passing/using the right name/ref from the html input into the javascript formdata.append. I'm avoiding jquery and xhr version 2 solutions for the time being. I'm determined to make this work if possible.

html input

```
<input id="newimg" type="file" onchange="changeimg(this.value,dbtable,dbid);">
```

javascript

```
function changeimg(filename,dbtable,dbid) {

  // ignor "c:\fakepath\" in filename
  var filename = document.getElementById('newimg').files[0].name;

  var formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
  formdata.append("dbtable",dbtable);
  formdata.append("dbid",dbid);
  formdata.append("filename",filename);

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
      // code for IE6, IE5
      var xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xhr.open("POST","/uploader.pl",true);
  xhr.send(formdata);

}
```

perl snippet which I'm currently using. This same code has been working well for me under "non javascript" page form submits.

```
#
my $upload_filehandle = $cgi->upload("filename");
#
open (UPLOADFILE, ">$newfile");
      binmode UPLOADFILE;
      while ( <$upload_filehandle> ) {
        print UPLOADFILE;
      }
close UPLOADFILE;
#
```

Comment: Which framework/module do you use on Perl side? Could you add your Perl code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the variables you are using refer to the file at all. That is why it isn't being included.

Instead of trying to send the filename, send the input.

Replace:

```
formdata.append("filename",filename);
```

with:

```
var file = document.getElementById("newimg").files[0];
formdata.append("newimg", file);
```

Better yet, stop getting data manually and just send the whole form in one go:

```
<input id="newimg" name="newimg" type="file" onchange="changeimg(this.form)">
```

and

```
function changeimg(form) {
  var formdata = new FormData(form);
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST","/uploader.pl",true);
  xhr.addEventListener("load", function () { alert("Loaded"); });
  xhr.send(formdata);
}
```

Comment: Your replace ... with... code is wrong, you don't append an img element to a FormData object also the syntax.

Comment: @Musa — There was a typo where I missed out a `)`, but `newimg` is a file input (as seen in the question) not an img element.

Comment: I was unaware that you could pass an html element to FormData.append

Comment: Oh drat, you can't. Serves me right for not checking when I never use that syntax. Just providing the form is much easier.

Comment: I think I may have an issue with multipart/form-data. I'm still getting 0 byte files which is the same issue I've had when the form Content-type is not multipart/form-data. I did try and add
    `xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data")`
right before the send but did not help. Still debugging...

Comment: Is form encType="multipart/form-data" the Content-type?

Comment: Explicitly setting the Content-Type header will mean that XHR will fail to read the content-type from the FormData object, so the boundary marker information will be missing from it and it will break. **Do not** add an explicitly content-type header.

Comment: Just noticed that the input is missing the name, that would break it when passing the form object. Form elements without names can't be successful controls.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to @Quentin example I was able to make it work using these changes. I still needed to append dbtable and dbid as they are not form varibales.

new html input

```
<input type="file" name="filename" onchange="changeimg(this.form,dbtable,dbid);">
```

new javascript

```
function changeimg(form,table,id) {
  var formdata = new FormData(form);
  formdata.append("item",id);
  formdata.append("table",table);
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST","/uploader.pl",true);
  xhr.addEventListener("load", function () { alert("Loaded"); });
  xhr.send(formdata);
}
```

no change to perl script